# How to see if two ArrayLists are from the same Type

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement the viewmodel observer with generics, doing this I wont need 7 observers since I'm collecting data from 7 different Fragments.

### The goal

Since this 7 fragments store the data inside different ArrayLists types I made a generic ViewModel class to pass that data to my main Activity (fragments holder)

### SharedViewModel

```
class SharedViewModel<T>: ViewModel() {

    var data:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun setData(anyData:ArrayList<T>){
        data.value = anyData
    }

    val getAnyData:LiveData<ArrayList<T>>
    get() = data

}
```

Doing this, I just set any array data type inside each fragment

```
  (activity as MainActivity).getViewModelInstance().setData(xArray)
```

And in my MainActivity I want to check if that xArray data type is the same type as the one declared globally at MainActivity, if they are equal it should assing the current array data values to the new empty array

### MainActivity

```
private var xArray = arrayListOf<Xclass>()

    onCreate()
    ...

     viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
            viewModel.getAnyData.observe(this, Observer { it:ArrayList<out Any?>
                if(it == xArray){
                    xArray.addAll(it)
                }
            })
```

### The purpose

If I do this, I prevent doing 7 observers in my MainActivity for each fragment and just update one observer with different array types, comparing them and reasigning them will be much less code and easier for me for the architecture.

### The problems

There are two problems

- The first one as mentioned, is just how to compare the current ArrayList got by the observer in my MainActivity to the array that I declared. They should check if both, **it** and **xArray** are `ArrayLists` of the same type
- Second error is this

  (activity as MainActivity).getViewModelInstance().setData(xArray)

At `.setData(xArray)` its highlighted red saying `Required: Nothing, Found:ArrayList<Xclass>`. Thats weird because the setData of SharedViewModel needs Any ArrayList to be passed.

Thanks

Comment: The most important thing now is to check if the arrays are from the same type, I have found isArrayOf method but it only compares the content of the array instead of the type defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought, I came up with a simple, but not fail proof method by utilizing a Class Type combined with the generics for full functionality. I believe this will handle your issues with reusability and removing redundant listeners in the way you were hoping.

```
class SharedViewModel <T> (val listType: Class<T>) : ViewModel() {

    var data: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<T>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun setData(anyData: ArrayList<T>) {

        data.value = anyData
    }

    inline fun <reified K> isOfInternalType(checkType: Class<K>): Boolean = checkType.typeName == listType.typeName
}
```

### Set Array Data through viewModel

```
class Xclass
var xArray = arrayListOf<Xclass>()

val viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).getViewModelInstance()
if (viewModel.isOfInternalType(Xclass::class.java) {
    viewModel.setData(Xclass)
}
```

### Main Activity

```
class Xclass
private var xArray = arrayListOf<Xclass>()

onCreate()
...

viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.getAnyData.observe(this, Observer { data: ArrayList<out Any?> ->
    if (viewModel.isOfInternalType(Xclass::class.java) {
        xArray.addAll(it)
    }
})
```

### Other Example Uses

```
// Examples of use cases outside of initial question

class ViewOne: SharedView<ClassOne>(ClassOne::class.java)
val testClass = ViewOne()

ViewOne().isOfInternalType(ClassTwo::class.java) // returns false
ViewOne().isOfInternalType(testClass::class.java) // Error: Cannot use captured type as reified parameter

ViewOne().isOfInternalType(ClassOne::class.java) // returns true
ViewOne().isOfInternalType(ClassOne().javaClass) // returns true
testClass.isOfInternalType(ClassOne::class.java) // returns true
```

What I have done is created an instance of the View's listType expected at instantiation. This needed to be done because classes do not support type reification like an inline function can.
This implementation assumes each View will have a static listType... This can be modified to resemble the following:

```
class SharedViewModel(listType: Class<*>) : ViewModel() {
    var listType: Class<*> = listType
    private set(value) {
        field = value
    }

    fun setData(anyData: ArrayList<*>) {
        data.value = anyData
    }

    fun updateListType(newType: Class<*>) {
        listType = newType
    }

    inline fun <reified K> isOfInternalType(checkType: Class<K>): Boolean =
        checkType.typeName == listType.typeName
}
```

### Variable type SharedViewModel Examples

```
class ViewOne: SharedView(ClassOne::class.java)

val testClass = ViewOne()

testClass.isOfInternalType(ClassOne::class.java) // returns true

testClass.updateListType(ClassTwo::class.java)

testClass.isOfInternalType(ClassOne::class.java)  // returns false now
testClass.isOfInternalType(ClassTwo::class.java)  // returns true now
```

With this implementation of the variable typing, you would want to chain your `isOfInternalType` with the `setData` so that you ensure your type safety

This should have enough functionality for you to be able to accomplish your architecture goals for this project, please let me know if I've misunderstood anything and can help further.

Comment: hi Benjamin, first , thanks so much to take the time to make this awesome answer. Second, since I instantiate my SharedViewModel inside my activity without extending it, how could I do the same as you do here ? Because if I extend your abstract SharedView , I lost all the activity functionallity

Comment: @CoffeeBreak Ah, I should have been more clear. I am making an edit to my answer. The abstract class would extend the ViewModel -- I removed this in my example so I could quickly test the code I was writing. So if you need to implement ViewModel functionality it would be done in the abstract class SharedView -- Also the class does not specifically need to be abstract, it will work being just a normal class as well

Comment: when you refer to ViewOne and ClassOne, you mean ViewOne, fragment 1 and ClassOne what ?

Comment: remember that I just need to do .setValue(array) from each fragment and in my main view check if those objects are equal

Comment: I will update my naming to make more sense to your example

Comment: It didnt work , because it does not let me put the xArray::class.java, and if I put the xClass::class.java it works but not working to the addAll method

Comment: I had a typo with the xArray::class.java, I have fixed that now. What is not working with the addAll? In the scratch file I have it is working. You might have to type cast the array after the check like: xArray.addAll(it as ArrayList<Xclass>)